# iPhone: Is it possible to rename the extension of a file?

Tags: iphone, email, filesystem, file-extensions

I have an iPhone 5. I am new to this world.

Example file:

```
MyFile.zip.jpg
```

... must be **renamed** to:

```
MyFile.zip
```

... or, if not possible or feasible, this file :

```
MyFile.jpg
```

... must be **renamed** to:

```
MyFile.zip
```

**Sumarizing**: I would like to acquire some **control of the extension** (the characters after the last dot `.`) in the name of the files.

Methods **easy** to perform for unexperienced users are preferred.

What could this be used for?
Example:
**Privacy** is something of the past, we must admit it. But some people (like me) still would like to be able to send, say, a private email that only the receiver will read.

**Sending encrypted files** is becoming forbidden for some email providers, like GMail (read their terms), so `.zip` or `.rar` encrypted are returned to the sender as failed. And installing **cryptographic programs** is a nightmare for common (and even experienced) users of something like an iPhone.
A simple workaround: send your files (a document if you just want to send text) **inside an encrypted file** (say .rar) like:

```
MyPrivateFile.rar
```

... but rename it to:

```
MyPrivateFile.jpg
```

The receiver must rename just the extension, and voila! : you both have succeeded in sending encrypted info via email.
But, as you know, the email program's **interface** in the iPhone is too simple. I am not very experienced in using it, but I think it does not allow... well, it does not allow many things, even file saving inside the phone, so renaming file extensions must be even more difficult.

Comment: Clever, clever...it works just fin in OS X. Have no idea about iOS. The problem (or not) is that mail can not read the file with "wrong" extension, so I have to save it and change the extension.

Comment: This technique has been used in the past by criminals to trick people into opening "images" that are really malware.  If they have not already done so, it would be wise for writers of e-mail clients and mail servers to REJECT MyPrivateFile.jpg if it is not actually a .jpeg file.  As for Gmail, why do they forbid encryption?  Could it be because they are NSA's biggest competition?  Sort of—it's because they make a lot of money showing advertisements chosen according to the content of your e-mails.

Answer (score 3):

Tho I have never had to do this before but I just checked and it seems that Dropbox allows you to rename files. So if you have a file attachment in email you can save an "image" file in an email to Dropbox and once there you can rename it.

A bit of a kludge but Dropbox accounts are free...

Comment: Awkward, but at least it is a solution. Thanks you, Steve. I hope someone will offer another more practical way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Change file extension in iPhone using Libterm, check out below YouTube video:

https://youtu.be/-uoYVp1V51M

Hide files & make files un-deletable in iPhone, check out below YouTube video:

https://youtu.be/cNmRyI_kc7w

Above links are of the videos of my channel (BIT Infotain). Libterm app which is a terminal emulator I installed for root browsing purpose, it just clicked to me to use shell commands (as in Unix) to work on files, like to hide, make read-only & rename. You can think of many things to do on files which otherwise not possible in ‘Files’ app.

Comment: Answers should be more than just links (which can break anytime, rendering the answer useless). Please summarize the solution directly in the answer post.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/326064)

Comment: Change file extension in iPhone using Libterm, check out below YouTube video:

https://youtu.be/-uoYVp1V51M

Hide files & make files un-deletable in iPhone, check out below YouTube video:

https://youtu.be/cNmRyI_kc7w

They are the links of the videos of my channel. Libterm app which is a terminal emulator, it just clicked to me to use shell commands (as in Unix) to work on files. You can think of many things to do on files which otherwise not possible in ‘Files’ app.

Comment: Thanks for coming back. Not sure your edit addressed the feedback you got: the idea here is to have an answer which is useful *without* having to follow the link.

Comment: Yes, so it is very much possible to change the extension of file and rename the entire file in iPhone ‘Files’ using a terminal emulator.

Comment: Starting iOS 16 version, Apple introduced the option to change the file extension in the FILES app itself

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS/iPadOS 16, users can now easily change file name extensions from the Files app. Just select Rename in the context menu.

Answer (score -1):

When I have a file that I cannot put in e-mail, I put it online and put the URL in the e-mail.